# How can I append a string to a constant in a Vue template?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a custom directive that takes a string as a value. I added a property to the prototype, $ANALYTICS_EVENTS, and I have a constants file that contains my strings.

My button appears on different pages and I need to attach the page name to it.

What I currently have is:

```
        <button
          v-analytics:click="$ANALYTICS_EVENTS.CONTINUE"
          :disabled="errors.any()"
          class="btn-primary uppercase fill"
          data-test="btn-identity"
          type="submit">{{ $t('create.continueCTA') }}</button>
```

where "$ANALYTICS_EVENTS.CONTINUE", evaluates to 'Continue'. What I need is for it to evaluate to "Consumer (pageName) Continue. I don't believe string interpolation can work.

I tried `'Consumer Create - '` "$ANALYTICS_EVENTS.CONTINUE", but I can not seem to find a way to make this work and I am reluctant to make repetitive, similar Continue constants.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just adding the strings using + ....

```html
<button
          v-analytics:click="'Consumer Create - ' + $ANALYTICS_EVENTS.CONTINUE"
          :disabled="errors.any()"
          class="btn-primary uppercase fill"
          data-test="btn-identity"
          type="submit">{{ $t('create.continueCTA') }}</button>
```

Comment: Yes, the result is "Consumer Create - undefined".

Comment: Can you show some code how you are reading the value or expression in custom directive... v-analytics:click